# Inject multiple service implementations with Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I would like to have Windsor inject multiple implementations of a service to a constructor.

My scenario is that I have multiple search providers that implement a common interface.  I would like to register each of these with windsor and then inject them into my search service so it can query each on in turn.

Is such a thing possible with Windsor? Is there a better approach than injecting multiple implementations into the constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection with Castle Windsor Container - Part II](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/InversionOfControlAndDependencyInjectionWithCastleWindsorContainerPart2.aspx) at DotNetSlackers. It shows how to pass an array of the same service interface to an object.

Comment: It would be nice to see a non-xml config version of this article

Comment: Similar, but using fluent config: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/03/castle-windsor-registering-and.html